# Background-repeat для текста

Tags: css3

Как сделать повтор текста через background-repeat?
так можно сделать на css? или это нужно делать на js?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Можно текст завернуть в SVG:

```css
.patterns {
  background:
  url('data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 48 30"><foreignObject width="50px" height="30px"><div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="color:red;font-size:8px">SVG TEXT <span style="color:transparent;font-size:8px">○</span></div></foreignObject></svg>') no-repeat,
  url('data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 48 30"><foreignObject width="50px" height="30px"><div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="color:gray;font-size:8px">SVG TEXT ○</div></foreignObject></svg>') repeat-x;
  background-position-x: calc(50% + 5px);
  width:100%;
  height:30px;
}
```

```html
<div class=patterns></div>
```

Comment: можете выровнять текст в одну строчку, как на изображении? в svg не очень разбираюсь

Comment: тем более там ещё кружочек между текстом, мне это сложно доделать. Можете показать как это делается?

Comment: Я кружочек юникодом добавил

Comment: а как выровнять относительно центрального текста?

Comment: Кружок немного портит картину с центровкой, пока не знаю как лучше исправить.

Comment: Подправил калькулятором `background-position-x: calc(50% + 5px);`